# Bootstrap navbar not centered properly on IE11

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer-11, navbar

I'm prototyping a very simple bootstrap navbar which I want with a maximum width of 600px, centered on the screen and fixed on top.

This is the html code:

```css
.navbar {
  max-width: 600px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#">MyLink</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div>
  <!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

That works well on Chrome and Firefox. However on IE11, the navbar is not centered and instead sticks to the left of the screen (the width of 600px is correctly applied).

After looking into the inspection screen, I could narrow down the issue to 'position:fixed' property applied to the .navbar-fixed-bottom and .navbar-fixed-top classes (bootstrap.min.css(5)).
When I deselect the 'position:fixed' property in IE inspection window, then position becomes 'static' and the navbar is centered. Note that 'position:static' is not what I'm looking for neither because then the navbar is not fixed on top of the screen anymore obviously.

Does anyone know why IE would not centered the navbar properly with 'position:fixed' property applied to the nav element while it works fine for other browser?
Is there any existing workaround for that?

Please let me know if I'm not doing things correctly here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to the `navbar-fixed-top` class. Simply apply `width: 100%` and you should be good.

```css
.navbar.navbar-default {
  max-width: 600px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#">MyLink</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div>
  <!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: this is actually the best answer, then I don't need to worry about the media query

Answer (score 0):

it dosen't work because of `max-width`.Try this:

```
.navbar {
 width: 600px;
 margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: It works indeed. However a width fixed to 600px is too big for small screen size. I want the  navbar width to resize automatically and fits small screen nicely. I could specify a fixed width for each screen sizes in media queries I guess, just wondering if that's best practice.

Comment: yups either use media queries or other scales such as vh, vw etc for responsive design